# Restrict Site Contents in Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, office365

First post so be kind.

I have a customer list in Sharepoint that holds staff absence requests.  This has an approval workflow attached to it.  I have tried to ensure that staff cannot see each other's absence request and it seems to work.  Staff have contribute access to the subsite the list is held on.

I just noticed that staff can see the cog at the top right of the screen and can therefore access site contents and view the list.

Can anyone suggest a way in which to leave staff with contribute but restrict their access to site contents?

I am using Office 365 and therefore sharepoint online.

Many thanks,

Kevin Rodger

Answer (score 0):

Rather than trying to remove the site contents link, you may be able to limit what they can see when they try to specifically view the absence requests list.

You can set the default view of the list to exclude any items that are not their own, remove all other public views, and then change their permissions so that they cannot create personal or public views on that list (you may need to create a new permission level for that).

If any owners or approvers need to see more complete views, you can create a page and add a view of the requests list to it, then set permissions on that page so that only the desired owners/approvers have access to it.